# Making Javascript Function inaccessible from console

Tags: javascript

I am working on a **javascript** file with **javascript** `functions` that are not inside a closure. 
Obviously the function is callable by the console.

I know that adding a closure is best practice. But while tinkering i found that if I add in my file

```
window.myFunction = {}
```

the function becomes unavailable through the console.
Is this safe ?

Comment: That assigns a new empty object as the value of your function, and so, your function won't be a function any more. You won't be able to call it in the console or anywhere else.

Comment: In fact what happened to me was I created an instance of the object and then set it to {}, that's why it worked (because later I was calling the instance and not the object itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All global variables/functions in Javascript (Browser) are a property of the window object:

```
var x = "foo";
console.log(window.x); //foo
```

It's **not best practice** to pollute the global scope, but it isn't "unsafe" if you control which scripts your page uses. (Although I **don't** recommend using global variables)

If you do need to have a global variable, consider using a name that you know other script won't use:

```
(function(window, undefined){
   var privateVar = 5;

   window.mySite = {
     foo: "bar",
     func: function(){
        return "foo";
     }
   };

})(window);

console.log(window.mySite.func()); //"foo"
console.log(privateVar) //undefined
```

Now outside of the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression)  you can use `window.mySite` or just `mySite`, while `privateVar` won't be accessible.

More info on the window object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/window)